# My Projects thows error of syncfusion_flutter_gauges

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion-chart

AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_gauges-19.4.54/lib/src/radial_gauge/pointers/marker_pointer_renderer.dart:631:34: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.

- 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('../../../../fvm/default/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
  _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.8)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: My Flutter version is 2.8.1

Comment: `syncfusion_flutter_gauges: 19.4.50`. flutter clean and try

Comment: still same error accurs, should i upgrade my flutter sdk ??

Comment: `syncfusion_flutter_gauges: 19.4.48` it will solve most probably .other version need 2.10

Comment: yes, its worked for me. thanks